# Calling a local API using the fetch method

Tags: node.js, react-native, api

So I'm trying to call a local API using the fetch method but the problem is that I don't know exactly how to use the information retrieved, I copied some code from the internet but I don't think it makes sense :/, Can someone show me the correct way to use it? Thank you!

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  fetch('http://192.168.1.228:5001/api/GetTrainers') 
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setData({ message : responseJson.message.data })
    })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
   
  }); 

  function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

    return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
         
          keyExtractor={({ Trainerid }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.Trainerid}</Text>
            )}
          />
        )}
           </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
    fetch("http://192.168.1.228:5001/api/GetTrainers")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setData(responseJson.message.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ Trainerid }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.Trainerid}</Text>}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, after putting that the problem remains the same, I don't seem to get any result from that API call, what could be the problem?

Comment: So I tried changing my url with a ngrok one and i got this error : "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier “ngrok”
I couldn't find a solution for it :/